# How to take inputs from many widgets but only recalculate when submit button is pressed?

Tags: jupyter, ipywidgets

I have some code that takes inputs from a series of widgets and then does some calculations on a pandas DataFrame and prints the output. At the moment the calculations are triggered every time any of the widgets change. Given that the calculations take a bit of time to do I'd like to delay the calculations until I press a submit button widget. I can't quite work out how to tie the submit button to a function that then also reads the other widgets.

This is a simplified version of what I have:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

# input widgets that should only change the calcs after hitting the submit function
value_1 = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=0.5, min=0, max=1, step=0.05)
value_2 = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=0.5, min=0, max=1, step=0.05)

# submit button
submit_button = widgets.Button(description='submit')

# submit function
def submit():
    # I don't know what to put here to restrict the triggering of the recalculate function until
    # submit button is pressed
    pass

# recalculate function
def recalculate(value_1, value_2):
    # code to perform some calcs on a dataframe based on the widget inputs and print the result

# tie submit button to a function
submit_button.on_click(submit)

# code that ties the input calculations to the calculations
out = widgets.interactive_output(recalculate, {'value_1': value_1, 'value_2': value_2})

# display widgets
widgets.VBox([value_1, value_2, submit_button, out]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options.

Use `interact_manual` (https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#interact_manual):

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

# input widgets that should only change the calcs after hitting the submit function
value_1 = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=0.5, min=0, max=1, step=0.05)
value_2 = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=0.5, min=0, max=1, step=0.05)

# submit function
def submit():
    # I don't know what to put here to restrict the triggering of the recalculate function until
    # submit button is pressed
    pass

# recalculate function
def recalculate(value_1, value_2):
    return value_1 + value_2
    # code to perform some calcs on a dataframe based on the widget inputs and print the result

# tie submit button to a function
submit_button.on_click(submit)

# code that ties the input calculations to the calculations
out = widgets.interact_manual(recalculate, value_1= value_1, value_2= value_2)
```

Or roll your own, create your own output widget and control the display

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

# input widgets that should only change the calcs after hitting the submit function
value_1 = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=0.5, min=0, max=1, step=0.05)
value_2 = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=0.5, min=0, max=1, step=0.05)
out = widgets.Output()

# submit button
submit_button = widgets.Button(description='submit')



# recalculate function
def recalculate(value_1, value_2):
    return value_1.value + value_2.value
    # code to perform some calcs on a dataframe based on the widget inputs and print the result
    
# submit function
def submit(button):
    # I don't know what to put here to restrict the triggering of the recalculate function until
    # submit button is pressed
    total = recalculate(value_1, value_2)
    out.clear_output()
    with out:
        display(total)
    

# tie submit button to a function
submit_button.on_click(submit)

# code that ties the input calculations to the calculations
# out = widgets.interactive_output(recalculate, {'value_1': value_1, 'value_2': value_2})

# display widgets
widgets.VBox([value_1, value_2, submit_button, out])
```

Comment: I used the second option, works a treat. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to "out.clear_output() / with out:"! I've been looking a long time for a way to update the interactive_output results from a function different than the linked one ("recalculate") and this finally does the trick :-)